# GNU autotools include file dependency tracking (.deps directories) for CUDA

Tags: include, dependencies, tracking, autotools, autoconf

I am using GNU autotools to build cuda project.  CUDA files are regular C++ files as far as preprocessor is concerned, however they use `.cu` extension and must use `nvcc` compiler which is g++ based NVIDIA compiler.  This breaks regular dependency tracking, .deps directories are not populated.  This means that if `.cu` file includes another file, changes to include file do not trigger recompilation of `.cu` file.

how can I modify my Makefile.am/configure.ac to enable tracking dependency for `.cu` files.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try writing an implicit ".cu.cc" rule for generating C++ files from the CUDA files.  Automake should then be able to track the dependencies of the .cc files, which should reflect back on the CUDA files.